# Defining methods with NSString with format

Tags: objective-c, ios

How do you define a method in your own classes that accepts an NSString with format?

I see several different things using it like `NSLog`, `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:(NSString *)predicateFormat, ...]` and of course `[NSString stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...]`

Also, in the header files, NSLog and stringWithFormat have the following after their declaration:
`NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2)`. Googling didn't help much with telling me what this meant.

Obviously the ellipsis is the format parameters, but I don't know how to deal with them in the method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for Objective-C methods with variable number of arguments. Here is how it's done:

Declaration in the header:

```
- (void)setContentByAppendingStrings:(NSString *)firstString, ... 
   NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;
```

Implementation:

```
- (void)setContentByAppendingStrings:(NSString *)firstArg, ...
{
    NSMutableString *newContentString = [NSMutableString string];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstArg);
    for (NSString *arg = firstArg; arg != nil; arg = va_arg(args, NSString*))
    {
        [newContentString appendString:arg];
    }
    va_end(args);

    contents = newContentString;
}
```

Source: [Cocoa With Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html).

Comment: The `NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION` macro has supplanted this specific use of `NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION` (for format strings with arbitrary variable parameters).

Comment: NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION takes 2 params. The first is the index of the format string, the second is the index of the '...'. So in this example + (id)errorWithCode:(NSInteger)code format:(NSString *)format, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(2,3);  2 is the format and 3 is ...

Comment: Thanks @malhal, been searching everywhere for this simple explanation. could fine nowhere. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You need to make use of some C-code:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)format,... {
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    while (format) {
        // do something with format which now has next argument value
        format = va_arg(argList, id);
    }
    va_end(argList);
}
```

And it's possible to forward the args in to `NSString` as follows:

```
- (void)someMethod:(NSString *)format,... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
}
```